# $("#myForm").attr("action") returns a form element instead of undefined for forms with no actions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, attr

I have this basic example:

```
<!doctype HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="jquery-1.4.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#showAction").click(function(){
                alert($("#myForm").attr("action"));
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="myForm">
    <input type="text" name="action" value="myAction" />
</form>
<input type="button" value="click me" id="showAction" />
</body>
</html>
```

When you click 'click me' you can see the tag

```
$("#myForm").attr("action");
```

Doesn't actually return an attribute of the  element.  It returns the child of the form with the name "action".

Is this expected behavior? Is this a bug in jQuery?

Comment: There's no action attribute on your form in the above example. Are you including one?

Comment: @Grillz: Lol, that's the point of the question.  If an action is not assigned in the <form> element the script looks at it's children, apparently.

Comment: Isn't `action` required on `<form>`? Not 100% sure about all modern standards etc; just making sure.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's a "bug" introduced by Netscape a long time ago (a boneheaded move, IMO), where `form.action` is a property because an element with that `name` is a child of the `<form>`.  So no, it's not really a jQuery bug, but a JavaScript one, depending on your point of view...jQuery just doesn't have any additional checks for these cases.

To be safe, don't name your elements `"action"` or `"submit"`, since it can mess with `form.submit()` as well.

Comment: A nice reminder that IE isn't the only culprit for the kludgy early days of the Internet. +1

Comment: +1 I suppose this is because, effectively, `$('form').attr('action')` is a wrapper for `$('form')[0].action`?

Comment: hah...it's funny Wordpress should choose to require an 'action' parameter to be posted to it's admin-ajax.php script to process forms.

Comment: @lonesomeday - it'll [fall back to that](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/attributes.js#L345), yes :)

Comment: @Nick Presumably your advice goes for `method`, `enctype`, `accept` and `accept-charset` as well?

Comment: @lonesomeday - if they're not defined on the `<form>`, yes, any property will fall back and give some unexpected results

Comment: This is NOT a bug. If, however, you do not know the properties of a FORM element, you can easily introduce a bug (overriding the form's action attribute/property with an element named the same) into your non-well-formed HTML document. As already stated, just don't use reserved words as form element names.

Answer (score 2):

Very odd indeed. I am going to quietly say - *bug*...

Form with an `action` attribute: http://jsfiddle.net/vMTYY/

Form without an `action` attribute: http://jsfiddle.net/ZWWTm/